# Get Website Articles into Android App

Tags: android, web-scraping, rss

i want to Make news application for android that can get News from news Websites.
how can i do for websites that don't have RSS pages ?
Whats the Best Way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like web scraping, using library like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), will parse the HTML page into objects for you to use.